# Is There have Rate UserControl can be use Windows phone Application？

Tags: windows-phone-7, user-controls, rate

as we know.
when we use listBox to display date and sometimes specific data rate. 
 i was try draw by myself 。but UI effect does not look good。
So is There have Rate UserControl can be Use Windows phone Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes There have Rate UserControl can be use Windows phone Application.